# convert Rows to column

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, pivot

Looking for the way to change row to column. (The comflag is of type bit and not null). Help appreciated

```
Table1
Id    Commflag    value
122   0           Ce
125   1           Cf
122   0           Cg
125   1           cs
```

Here is what I want in result

```
id    ce    cf    cg    cs    cp
122   0     null  0     null  null
125   null  1     null  1     null
```

The below query shows error-

```
 SELECT ID , [CE],[CF],[CG],[CS],[CP]
   FROM TABLE1
  PIVOT ((convert((Commflag)as varchar()) FOR value IN [CE],[CF],[CG],[CS],[CP] as pvt
  ORDER BY date
```

Comment: Can you verify my edit of the second code block; I had to add `null` for the `cp` value of id `122`

Comment: You have to add parentheses around your values. VALUE IN ([CE], ... ) In fact, your parentheses are all messed up.

Comment: Next time it would be more helpful if you would post the error instead of just saying it shows an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query does what you want:

```
select Id, pvt.Ce, pvt.Cf, pvt.CG, pvt.Cs, pvt.Cp
from 
(
 select Id, cast(Commflag as tinyint) Commflag, value
 from Table1
) t
pivot (max(Commflag) for value in ([Ce],[Cf],[CG],[Cs],[Cp])) pvt
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/29c5a3/1/0)

Here's another way to do it, without using `PIVOT`:

```
select Id,
max(case value when 'Ce' then CAST(Commflag as tinyint) else null end) Ce,
max(case value when 'Cf' then CAST(Commflag as tinyint) else null end) Cf,
max(case value when 'Cg' then CAST(Commflag as tinyint) else null end) Cg,
max(case value when 'Cs' then CAST(Commflag as tinyint) else null end) Cs,
max(case value when 'Cp' then CAST(Commflag as tinyint) else null end) Cp
from Table1
group by Id
order by Id
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/29c5a3/2/0)